# Space in the center of a Horizontal wordpress menu

Tags: wordpress, list, menu, placeholder

I am looking for a solution to a unique problem. I have a wp_menu underneath the "Network Menu" on a theme I developing for a multisite build. There is a little ring in the center of the menu that holds the logo, and I am curious if there is a way to get a transparent list item to hold that place, and allow all other "legitimate" list items to wrap around that, so either to the left or right.

I already have a filter that inserts a list item that I can customize by adding css, I just don't know how to make one list item in particular hold the place where the circle exists.

The website is:
http://www.mountainjackscreative.com/sandbox/edts/sample-page/

Any help, or even just ideas would be great!

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery you could do some math on the menu.

**EDIT:** Put this before ending of your head tag

**LAST_EDIT:** Here's the JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BsnFW/14/. Last try :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    menuBreakPoint = 200; //width in px after which you want to insert the space (experiment with this)
    menuWidth = 0;
    rightMenuStart = 600; //width in px from left of menu container div to the right


    $('.sub_site_menu li').each( function() {
        menuWidth += $(this).width();
    if (menuWidth >= menuBreakPoint) {
       $(this).css('margin-left', (rightMenuStart - menuWidth));
       return false; //break out of each loop
    }
    });

});
```

Use this.

Comment: I have tried to implement the code you provided, but I am having a little trouble getting it to work properly.  I have this inserted in the head of my document.  Is that the right place?  I also renamed the menu to .sub_site_menu, and changed the numbers a little, with no luck.

Comment: Edited appropriately. You can also put it in a separate file and reference it by doing <script src="path/to/thejsfile.js"></script>

Comment: That did it!  Thanks a ton.  Jquery is on the list to learn next.  It unlocks a ton of possibilities!

Comment: Shoot!  False alarm.  For some reason it seemed to work.  I think that it is executing the function after the list item is added, and therefore creates room for error when it reaches the trigger item.  If there was a way to grab the list item's width, than add it, and then validate the overall width against the breakpoint, that would be ideal.  Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: Sorry, there's still an error in that JS fiddle for some reason... here's a working one [http://jsfiddle.net/BsnFW/9/](http://jsfiddle.net/BsnFW/9/)

Comment: I hate to say it, but seems like it's still performing the function, then adding the list item based on the previous test.  You can see the result at the site.  Currently I have the settings where I would want the gap to be.

Comment: Use padding on the list items instead of margin (padding: 10px;). Margin doesn't calculate into the width of the elements thus it doesn't create the gap where you want.

Comment: I am still having trouble getting this to work.  It may be time to start looking for an alternative method.  Got any last ditch efforts?  I can't thank you enough for your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not breakup the list into two? float one left and the other right. Provide the appropriate ul margins so nothing shows up on the logo?

Comment: The only problem with that is that the content is generated dynamically.  So each individual site will have differnent menu needs, so it would be best to have some sort of "gap" hard coded in the menu for the items to wrap around.  If it was a static menu, I would love to just make two separate lists, and float them over.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to go with the jquery solution as it will most likely render the best results across all browsers.  But I did stumble across this other resource regarding a soon to be implemented feature in CSS3

Included is a script that forces compatability with the new CSS3 "column" functionality.

http://www.csscripting.com/css-multi-column/